# Enable ox-hugo Auto-export on saving

Tags: org-mode, hugo

I am trying to establish an ox-hugo workflow using the Auto-saving feature described [in the official website](https://ox-hugo.scripter.co/doc/auto-export-on-saving/). However, when trying to enable it using the following snippet:

```
(("content-org/"
  . ((org-mode . ((eval . (org-hugo-auto-export-mode)))))))
```

I receive the following error:

> Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-function ("content-org/" (org-mode (eval org-hugo-auto-export-mode))))
>     (("content-org/" (org-mode (eval org-hugo-auto-export-mode))))

Any ideas why the official doc instructions would not be valid?

Comment: Where are you putting this snippet?  It should be in a file called `.dir-locals.el` in the project root.  Emacs has different evaluation rules for such a file and it looks, from yr debugger output, that they have not been applied in yr case.

Comment: @FranBurstall you were right, i was including the snippet in my .emacs file! I did not know there were differences in evaluation of these. If you make this an answer I'll gladly accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must put this snippet in file called `.dir-locals.el` in the project root.  This file is read by emacs with special evaluation rules in place which differ from those with which `.emacs` and most other `.el` files are read.